# How high should state be lifted in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Should intermediate components control parts of state and call props passed to them or should state be lifted higher?  I've been going back and forth whether to have the child component utilize local state or have it handled by higher component and pass additional props down.

In this limited example, I have a `Main` component.  I display some data in this component and pass functions to filter the data to a child component. Though, main component doesn't necessarily need to know about when the `menuOpen` property is changed.  However, I need to update `menuOpen` when `handleCancel()`, `handleSave()`, and `handleButtonClick()` are called.

`handleCancel()` and `handleSave()` both modify the data that is displayed so I declare them in the `Main` component.

Should I be passing all these `props` through from `Main` component or use intermediate components to handle smaller portions of local state but also call `props` from a parent (grandparent etc) component?

### Main Component

```
//Parent component
class Main extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      checkBoxes: {
        1: {
          name: 'Apple',
          isChecked: true,
        },
        //...
      },
      fruit: {
        1: {
          name: 'Apple',
        },
        //...
      },
      checkedBoxes: [],
    };

    this.baseState = JSON.stringify(this.state.checkBoxes);
    this.fruitFilter = this.fruitFilter.bind(this);
    this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.resetState = this.resetState.bind(this);
  }

  resetState() {
    this.setState({checkBoxes: JSON.parse(this.baseState)});
  }

  //populates the checkedboxs array with name to filter by
  handleSave() {
    const checkedBoxes = Object.keys(this.state.checkBoxes)
      .filter(key => {
        //....some logic 
      });

    this.baseState = JSON.stringify(this.state.checkBoxes);
    this.setState({checkedBoxes: checkedBoxes});
  }

  //handles the checkbox toggle
  handleChange(e) {
    const checkBoxes = {...this.state.checkBoxes};
    checkBoxes[e.target.id].isChecked = e.target.checked;
    this.setState({checkBoxes: checkBoxes});
  }

  //filteres the fruit - if nothing is checked return them all
  fruitFilter(fruit) {
    return Object.keys(fruit)
      .filter(key => {
        //...filter logic 
      })
  }

  render() {
    const visibleFruits = this.fruitFilter(this.state.fruit);
    return (
      <div>
        <Filter
          resetState={this.resetState}
          checkBoxes={this.state.checkBoxes}
          handleSave={this.handleSave}
          handleChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <div>
          <h2>Filtered Fruit</h2>
          {Object.keys(visibleFruits).map(key => {
            return (
              //... renders list of fruit
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

## Child Component

```
class Filter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      menoOpen: false,
    };

    this.handleCancel = this.handleCancel.bind(this);
    this.handleSave = this.handleSave.bind(this);
    this.handleButtonClick = this.handleButtonClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleSave() {
    this.setState({menuOpen: false});
    this.props.handleSave();
  }

  handleCancel() {
    this.setState({menuOpen: false});
    this.props.resetState();
  }

  handleButtonClick() {
    this.setState({menuOpen: !this.state.menuOpen});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleButtonClick}>Choose Fruits</button>
        {this.state.menuOpen && (
          <FilterMenu
            checkBoxes={this.props.checkBoxes}
            handleSave={this.handleSave}
            handleCancel={this.handleCancel}
            handleChange={this.props.handleChange}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

### Grandchild Component

```
const FilterMenu = ({checkBoxes, handleChange, handleCancel, handleSave}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(checkBoxes).map(key => {
        return (
          //... renders dropdown menu
        );
      })}
      <button onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
      <button onClick={handleSave}>Save</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Don't lift states that parent does not need to know to parent. It's fine to call both `setState` and `this.props` in your event handlers.

Answer (score 0):

Refine the separation of concerns and I think you'll like it better.

- Define all checkbox event handlers in `Filter`.
- `Filter` communications with `Main` via state only.

  - Don't force `Main` to evaluate UI components to set state.
  - Define `Main` state for `Filter` to use as needed to avoid the above.
- `Filter` will construct the checkboxes.
- `Cancel` and `Save` buttons seem like `Filter` level functions to me.
- A `FilterMenu` component now seems pointless because it does not *do* anything. Perhaps in the larger architecture it is useful but you can always re-factor it out of `Filter` when needed
- `Filter` component is the seam in the code that separates action from state.

  - State is not unnecessarily pushed further down.
  - Actual functionality is not unnecessarily pushed further up.
  - Coupling between `Main` and `Filter` is reduced. `Filter` has more reuse potential.

Comment: Trying to understand this.  I should declare `handleCheckboxChange` at the filter level, as well as `cancel` and `save`.  Within those declarations, I need to pass the changes to `Main` where the state will be changed?

Comment: I'm really thinking about how to make state a single object. So I'm thinking about `Main` as the state Of course UI and state must meet somewhere and `Filter` is where all the UI action is happening. Honestly what I really want to say is [use Redux!](https://redux.js.org/basics)

Comment: I like Redux. I think it would be like putting out candle with a fire-hose in this case, however.  I think this pattern is common enough that I should understand it.

Comment: yeah, I agree. I did not want to bring up Redux in the first place but I'm trying to get at an idea of a single state object and code structure that facilitates that. All that should reduce your direct concern, lots of passing state and props especially with the fragmentation. Coherent components should help.